# Problema el retornar cadenas con ñ en MySQL desde Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, unicode

Estoy utilizando una base de datos MySQL con una aplicación Spring.

La base de datos debe tener datos de carácter personal encriptados. Esto se hace con `AES_ENCRYPT`. Se obtienen los datos con `AES_DECRYPT` para mostrarlos.

El problema es que al devolver cadenas que deben incorporar `ñ`, tildes o caracteres especiales, no se muestran como tal y sí modificados (`ñ` como `Ã±`).

¿Alguien sabe como devolver desde la base de datos los caracteres correctos?

Entiendo que los está almacenando ya modificados (`Ã±` en vez de `ñ`) en un campo `VARBINARY`.

**EDITADO**

Para la table se está utilizando `utf8 - utf_spansih_ci`. El tema es que en los campos que no son `VARBINARY` se almacena de forma correcta.

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a que encontraras la solución, por favor considera **[aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** haciendo click en el **✅** a la izquierda de la respuesta.

Comment: Ya lo hice Mariano, a todas

Comment: @user1748166 Sería bueno que supieras la diferencia entre votar (positivamente o negativamente) un post, y marcar una respuesta como la correcta. Lo primero se hace con las flechas hacia arriba y abajo, que están en la parte izquierda del post. No es obligación votar, pero si sientes que hizo un aporte positivo o negativo, entonces es recomendable que votes acorde a esto.

Comment: @user1748166 Por otro lado, cuando una respuesta soluciona tu problema, lo recomendable es que la selecciones como la crespuesta correcta, marcando la marca ✅ que está bajo las flechas para los votos (dejándola de color verde)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, tienes que indicarle que es un carácter especial de `utf8_spanish`.

```sql
SELECT nombre 
  FROM empleados 
 WHERE nombre
  LIKE '%ñ%' COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
```

Comment: Al ajecutars la consulta:

Comment: Al ejecutar la consulta `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(campo,clave) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci FROM table` da un error `COLLATION not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'`

Comment: Genial, funcinó!

Answer (score 1):

¿El cotejamiento de la base de datos está en utf8? Si no es asi modificala con

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Estoy accediendo por dos vías. Por workbench o bien por una aplicación Java Spring MVC. La base de datos está ya en `utf-8`, los campos almacenados en un campo VARCHAR si que se almacenan de forma correcta. El problema es con los `VARBINARY` después de hacer un `AES_ENCRYPT` y ÀES_DECRYPT`

Answer (score 1):

Si la declaración de tabla de códigos de la tabla está hecha en base a utf8 y aún así no devuelve los caracteres "especiales", es probable que se esté accediendo al Servidor de Datos con una aplicación que está configurada bajo otra tabla de códigos.
Prueba a ejecutar una consulta previa para solicitar los datos en utf8: `SET NAMES utf8`. Esta consulta provocará que el servidor devuelva los resultados codificados en utf8.
También cabe la posibilidad que los datos estén corrompidos desde su almacenamiento, esto es, que se envíen codificados en una tabla de código no esperada.
NOTA: Para el uso de los caracteres de la lengua española, es recomendable usar la declaración de `utf8_spanish_ci`.

Comment: La tabla ya está en `utf8_spanish_ci`. Estoy insertando desde workbench, y en todos los casos me devuelve la `ñ` modificada

Answer (score 0):

El problema se resolvió haciendo

```
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(campo, clave) AS CHAR) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
```

Desde Spring singue sin funcionar, ¿sabe alguien como forzar el COLLATION en un `ComboPooledDataSource`? Solo con incluir el COLLATE en las querys no está funcionando

Se tuvo que cambiar el charset del server a utf8, desde latin1, porque sino entra en conflicto.